# iPad, Old app icon shows for fraction of seconds while moving to background

Tags: ios, ipad

For our iPad app, I have replaced the old set of icons with the new ones. When I try to over install a build with new set of app icons on the market build, New app icon appears. But when I move from running state to background old app icon is shown for fraction of seconds before the new one.

After rebooting the device or Reset Home Screen Layout everything works fine.([app icon did not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341790/app-icon-did-not-refresh))

Have tried clean+build, deleting derived data.Moving to asset catalog. Nothing worked.

Want to know if this is ios bug and if there are any apple support/discussion forum links to this OR am I doing something wrong?

Comment: delete app from simulator or ipad and then run xcode

Comment: If I delete the app and install again it'll be fine. But on over install this issue occurs.